# Is it possible to run certain layers of a network on different devices on Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have been trying to run inference on a custom Tensorflow model on Movidius Neural Compute Stick. The problem is, the final layer is unsupported by NCSDK. Since the final layer is computationally quite light, I would like to know if there is a possibility to run that layer on CPU?

My previous searches led me to these:

[Distributed Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed)

[Placing Variables on CPU](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9517)??

I just need to be able to run inference up to a certain layer on the NCS, then process the last layer on CPU.

Comment: How do you build the model? If you're using the TensorFlow Python API, could you use a `with tf.device("/cpu:0"):` block to pin the ops in the last layer to the CPU?

Answer (score 1):

Using mvNCCompile and the -in and -on options of NCS might help. Compile a model with -in input and then use -on  to specify the output node as the last node that you need to run on NCS. This will create a graph file that takes input from the input node and give the output node. So instead of processing the data through the entire model, you can get the output of the intermediate results of whatever node you choose.

After getting the result from intermediate layer from NCS, you might have to give this as input to the last layer which has to run on CPU.

[You could find a similar discussion in the link.](https://ncsforum.movidius.com/discussion/971/how-does-ncs-support-caffe-custom-layers)